# Dependency Injection in Custom Class - .NET Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

A NET.Core project and I'm trying to inject the dependency injection in my custom class `ClassB` but however for some reason I am unable to get it done.

The value of `path` shows *null*.

Below is my code.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.Configure<OptionsConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("OptionsConfig"));
    services.Configure<ClassB>(Configuration.GetSection("OptionsConfig"));
}
```

OptionsConfig

```
public string path { get; set; }
```

appsettings.json

```
  "OptionsConfig": {
    "path": "~/abc/"
  },
```

Class A

```
Class A{
   ClassB _B = new ClassB();
   var outMsfg = _B.Show();
}
```

Class B

```
public class ClassB
{
    private readonly OptionsConfig _options;

    public ClassB() { }

    public ClassB(IOptions<OptionsConfig> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    public void Show()
    {
     string outputFileName = Path.Combine(_options.path+ ".pdf");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Dependency injection does not work this way. As per definition

> Dependency injection is a programming technique that makes a class independent of its dependencies. **It achieves that by decoupling the usage of an object from its creation**.

By using `new` inside the class you are using it you are by definition not using dependency injection.

```
Class A{
   ClassB _B = new ClassB();
   var outMsfg = _B.Show();
}
```

Since you are using `new ClassB()` you can't expect the other constructor to execute `public ClassB(IOptions<OptionsConfig> options)`

If anything I would expect this:

```
Class A{
   ClassB _B;
   
   public ClassA(IOptions<OptionsConfig> options) {
       _B = new ClassB(options);
   }

   // This should be inside a function
   var outMsfg = _B.Show();
}
```

Even this way, the class `A` should also be injected inside a controller, so you should also declare an interface `interface IA` that `class A` should implement and configure dependency injection to inject it to a controller.

```
services.AddScoped<IA, A>();
```

Check documentation for [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to understand it.

Comment: Hello @Athanasios Kataras here is new version as per your suggestions but again it didn't worked out.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73209862/dependency-injection-and-configurations-net-core