# Dependency Injection and Configurations - .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, microservices

Creating a standalone project which read JSON and simply response back. Trying to make the best use of dependency injection. However, I've few questions to clarify.

So firstly `HomeController` is called which has a dependendency on `ClassA`, so after refactoring `ClassA` implements `IClassA` and Updating `Startup.cs`,  `HomeController` can now successfully use the instance created by the Startup.cs to invoke the method `_IClassA.GetOP(data)`.

Now I see similar behavior where `ClassA` has a dependency on `ClassB` , `UtiClass` & `Document` class. So do I need to create Interfaces for all to remove the `new` keyword used for creating instances.

Again, my primary focus is to retrieve the value of `KeysAndValues` -> `path`. So in `ClassA` constructor I instantiated `ClassB` and pass the `IOptions<KeyAndValue>`. Unfortunately, I am unable to get the value of `options.path`. Please help to clarify my doubts and kindly solve this puzzle. Thank you.

```
//HomeController
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IClassA _IClassA;
        public HomeController(IClassA iClassA)
            _IClassA = iClassA;

        public string Get(DTO_A data)
            var result = _IClassA.GetOP(data);
}

//INTERFACE
public interface IClassA
        public string GetOP(DTO_A data);

//Class
 public sealed class ClassA : IClassA

        //private readonly IClassB _IClassB; //Cannot Instantiated
        private readonly ClassB _ClassB;
        public ClassA(IOptions<KeysAndValues> options) 
            _ClassB = new ClassB(options);

        Document request = new Document();
        UtiClass objUtiClass = new UtiClass();

        public string GetOP(DTO_A data)
        {
            request.Name = data.Name;
            objUtiClass .Document = request;
           _ClassB.UpdateMethod(objUtiClass );
        }

public class Document : IDocument
    {}

public class ClassC
    {}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IClassA, ClassA>();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddScoped<IClassB, ClassB>();
            services.Configure<KeysAndValues>(Configuration.GetSection("KeysAndValues"));
        }
```

```
public class ClassB : IClassB
        private IOptions<KeysAndValues> options;

        public ClassB(IOptions<KeysAndValues> options)
            this.options = options;

        public void UpdateMethod(UtiClass req)
           string fille = Path.Combine(options.path);
        }
```

```
public class KeysAndValues
        public string path { get; set; }
```

Comment: ```string outputFileName = Path.Combine(new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build().GetSection("KeysAndValues")["Path"]);``` is an alternative solution but again I would rather use Model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like how class `HomeController` requires interface `IClassA`, class `ClassA` needs to require interface `IClassB`. Class `ClassB` is the one that requires `IOptions<KeysAndValues>`, because it's `ClassB` that actually needs the `path` value.

Now, you don't *need* to use interfaces at all here. However, I'd recommend using interfaces because it makes your life much easier should you add unit testing.

Here's what it would look like with interfaces.

```
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IClassA _IClassA;
    public HomeController(IClassA iClassA)
    {
        _IClassA = iClassA;
    }
}

public interface IClassA { }
public interface IClassB { }

public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    private readonly IClassB _IClassB;
    public ClassA(IClassB iClassB)
    {
        _IClassB = iClassB;
    }
}

public class ClassB : IClassB
{
    private readonly KeysAndValues options;
    public ClassB(IOptions<KeysAndValues> options)
    {
        this.options = options.Value;
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    
    services.AddTransient<IClassA, ClassA>();
    services.AddTransient<IClassB, ClassB>();
    services.Configure<KeysAndValues>(Configuration.GetSection("KeysAndValues"));
}
```

If you don't want to use interface, just remove all the interfaces and replace all constructor parameters with the concrete class, and modify `ConfigureServices` with

```
services.AddTransient<ClassA>();
services.AddTransient<ClassB>();
```

I'd recommend `AddTransient` over `AddScoped`. Use Scoped only if you need information from the HTTP request/response explicitly in that service. I'd also recommend *not* having any properties in a service (`Document request` and `UtiClass objUtiClass`) that are not `readonly` and set by DI, or you'll need to use `AddSingleton` and ensure you don't get race conditions (which your current code looks like it will).